# In iPhoto, convert MJPEG videos to H.264?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, video, photos.app, encoding

In iPhoto, I've got some old MJPEG videos that don't transfer to my iPod Touch. I've got new videos that I took with my iPod Touch that are in the H.264 format, so they transfer fine, of course.

How can I convert my MJPEG videos so that I can transfer them to my iPod? I assume I'd need to convert them to H.264 somehow. Is it possible to convert them, and keep the metadata associated with them as well, especially the date that the videos were taken?

Answer (score 1):

Probably need to use QuickTime for this (or maybe iMovie if you prefer) -- as far as built-in solutions go. There's a built-in setting in qt to export for iPod touch (as well as settings for other devices) using h.264.